# How to record audio from website (not from mic) using HTML or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, audio-recording

I want to record an audio from the website (not using or from mic) with HTML or JavaScript. For example, if user click a button, then website start record a sounds from its own and save it.

But I can't find how to record audio from website. When I search about this, I can found so many way to record audio from mic but no website.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Audio cannot be "recorded", in the strict sense of the word, without a transducer.  Please clarify the source of the audio.

Comment: What sounds ? Where does it come from ? If you know how to record an mic, then you should know that you just need to know how to get an MediaStream from **your**  sounds.